# Create and solve a simple extended form game in Python API to Gambit

Tags: python, game-theory

I would like to create a simple, perfect information, extensive form game in the Python API to Gambit. The Python API documentation is [here](https://gambitproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyapi.html), but I can't figure out how to make a game completely in Python. I understand how to load an external game file and solve that, but I can't build it completely in Python.

I've gotten this far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gambit
g = gambit.Game.new_tree()
p = g.players.add("Alice")
p2 = g.players.add("Gaston")
g.root.insert_move(p, 2)
```

But I don't know how to add moves after and most importantly I don't know how to add the payoffs for the two players.

To make this question more precise, I would like to solve the simple game illustrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive-form_game#Perfect_and_complete_information). That is, I want to be able to input the tree shown in the diagram in the Python script, and add the four payoffs at the terminal nodes, and solve for the equilibrium (which in the simple example would be U,D') and the corresponding payoff (which is (2,1)).

Note that I would like to do this without converting to a normal form game.

Comment: I think you need to see [this page from documentation](https://gambitproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gui.html). And [this page](https://gambitproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html) from documentation about how to use the file format. One example with **building a game tree** can be seen at [this page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/gambit-project.org/games2016/buildtree.ipynb).